# delete values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Doing a web scraping project, and tangled myself into a problem.

I have this "data" dictionary with duplicates.

In the data dictionary:

I have unique keys, I would like to remove all values of a particular key wherein the value "the first part of the string" before "," is same and keep the last value.

For example:

```
data={
    'Peter Rabbit (2018)': 'AMC Norwalk 20,95 min,Animation|Adventure|Comedy|Family|Fantasy,User Rating: 6.5,Metascore:52,Showtimes:12:40 pm',
    'Tomb Raider (2018)': 'Studio Movie Grill - Downey,118 min,Action|Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Thriller,User Rating: 6.8,Metascore:48,Showtimes:11:10 am|1:55 pm|4:40|7:35|10:20\n<br>
    AMC Norwalk 20,118 min,Action|Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Thriller,User Rating: 6.8,Metascore:48,Showtimes:11:10 am|1:55 pm|4:40|7:35|10:20\n<br>
    AMC Norwalk 20,118 min,Action|Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Thriller,User Rating: 6.8,Metascore:48,Showtimes:4:45 pm|10:25'}
```

As 'Peter Rabbit (2018)' key has one values we will skip it. Now, Tomb Raider (2018) has 3 values, I need to split based on "," for the first value of each value, I will get

Studio Movie Grill - Downey
AMC Norwalk 20
AMC Norwalk 20

I would like to remove 1 to n instance of duplicate entries and keep Nth value

The final output will be

```
data={
        'Peter Rabbit (2018)': 'AMC Norwalk 20,95 min,Animation|Adventure|Comedy|Family|Fantasy,User Rating: 6.5,Metascore:52,Showtimes:12:40 pm',
        'Tomb Raider (2018)': 'Studio Movie Grill - Downey,118 min,Action|Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Thriller,User Rating: 6.8,Metascore:48,Showtimes:11:10 am|1:55 pm|4:40|7:35|10:20\n<br>
        AMC Norwalk 20,118 min,Action|Adventure|Drama|Fantasy|Thriller,User Rating: 6.8,Metascore:48,Showtimes:4:45 pm|10:25'}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the best-known method to achieve this output?
2. Should I split the values based on "," or "\n
   "?
3. Does python dictionary has any functions I can utilize?

Any assistance will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just advise to declare multiple values for a key like this:

```
data = {
    'key1': 'value',
    'key2': ['value1', 'value2'],
}
```

Then you can simply iterate over the corresponding keys' values and filter them appropriately.

Also, take a look at Python3 docs:
[Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries),
[Mapping types - dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)